# Generate Oracle Table(s) from XML Schema

Tags: xml, oracle, xsd

I've been tasked with reporting data to a third party. The third party has supplied detailed XML and XSD files for the format the data MUST be in. My data is in an Oracle DB (10g 10.2.4.0) spread across 20+ tables. I can write the query to generate the required data, no problem.

My thinking, which I admit may be flawed, is to somehow use the supplied XML/XSD files to generate a single table in Oracle, write my query to build my data and feed it into the table I've created. When I'm ready to send it I can just query the table using the dbms_xmlgen.newContext function.

Where I'm stuck is trying to generate my Oracle table from the XML/XSD files. I've found plenty of information on generating XML from an Oracle table, but not vice versa.

The only Oracle tool I'm very familiar with is PL/SQL Developer.

This is my first time asking a question on Stackoverflow and I'm a young developer, so please be gentle.

Comment: One table means there are no repeating elements or other particles,such as xsd:sequence... Or that you expect a denormalized structure... Which one is it?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but I believe what I'm saying is no repeating elements. For example, let's say I own 500 buildings and have to answer a series of 50 questions per building. The table would have one row per building with each column being an answer to a question about it. No building would ever appear twice in the table.

Comment: You can create XML data directly in oracle.  Go read this - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16659/toc.htm

Comment: If still interested, is there a way to share the XSD (if not publicly, you can email it to the support address on my website)? If not shareable, can you download the eval from my website, load your XSD in the editor, switch to the ADO.NET DataSet view, and if it works, send me a screenshot of the set?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this further and reviewing the Oracle XML DB documentation, I decided to use XSD.exe to create classes based on the XSD. I can then write a fairly simple .NET app to create instances, populate with my Oracle SQL results and serialize out as XML.

I recognize this doesn't answer my original question, but it's a far easier approach than trying to create tables based on the XSD. The Oracle XML DB documentation is daunting and seems like a real PITA.